# calculation of the direct limit of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose $\mathbb{Z} \overset{1}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{3}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{4}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\cdots$.

How to compute the direct limit of above groups?Does there exist a general method to calculate the direct limit of groups?

Comment: Is the $n$th map "multiplication by $n$"? Something else?

Comment: I want to know the general method,the method mentolioned there is a bit tricky.

Comment: Yes, the nth map is multiplication by n

Comment: What's tricky about the method in the link Ayman posted? Seems fairly general.